# How to implement internal/powerful site search functionality ?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have developed a site for our company, till now there is no search functionality in it. Now we are thinking to develop a site's search facility. Most of the times our page content comes from db. We have HTML editor by which our employee enter HTML content to db and later that content is shown on page but few things are still static, which means few things are hardcoded in the page, those are also important like menu content etc. now i want that when user put some word for search then that will search against database and file because that word may be hard coded in file. so guide me how to develop this kind of search where search will be based on file & database. if possible discuss here and also drive me toward article. thanks

Comment: if you know what and how indexing is you can go by a total custom indexing, or buy a ready to use library and make the interface only.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, the following MSDN code sample shows how to implement a search engine that can search contents (articles or posts...) in an ASP.NET website. It actually searches DB content...

[Implement Search Engine in ASP.NET (CSASPNETSearchEngine)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETSearchEngine-52f5392c#content)

Comment: its a nice sample, but is actually only a return data from the database using the `Like`, nothing about indexing the data. So its wrong to call this "implement a search engine"